# mapping a specific key to every entry in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array with 28166 values named `$mediaarray`, and another multidimensional array named `$mediafiletype`, which has 96 values.

Each entry in `$mediaarray` has a value named `file_type_id` that is a primary key in `$mediafiletype`. So what I'm trying to do is for each element in `$mediaarray` (total 28166 values), if the value `file_type_id` in `$mediaarray` is equal to `id` in `$mediafiletype` (total 96 values) then add the value `base_url` from `$mediafiletype` to the key of a newly formed multidimensional array, which is the same as `$mediaarray` but with a `base_url` now as a key.

The problem is, that I'm unable to map every value from `$mediaarray` with a key and store it back into a new array and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any advise would be grand.

Here's my code

```
$baseUrlKeyMediaArray = array();
$NotbaseUrlKeyMediaArray = array();

foreach ($mediaarray as $key => $mavalue) {

    $match = false;

    foreach ($mediafiletype as $mftvalue) {
        if ($mavalue['file_type_id'] == $mftvalue['id']) {
            $pathname = $mftvalue['base_url'];
            $baseUrlKeyMediaArray[$pathname] = $mavalue;
            $match = true;
        }
    } 
    if(! $match) {
        $notsure[] = $mavalue;
    }
}
```

regards mike

Comment: isn't `$notsure` supposed to be `$NotbaseUrlKeyMediaArray` in your example...?

Comment: Your approach would result in 28166 * 96 cycles, which is ok, but unecessary. Why not *map* (indexing a new array by the id) the `$mediafiletype`-array by the relevant id first, and after this is done, you could traverse `$mediaarray` **once**, access the filetype directly and apply the needed values. Resulting in only 28166 + 96 cycles.

Comment: a little help: I tested your code, but replaced `$notsure` with `$NotbaseUrlKeyMediaArray` and it worked ok, unless you're looking for something else: [http://3v4l.org/FT3H3](http://3v4l.org/FT3H3)

Comment: Instead of describing your array structures and desired outcome in words, please do so in code. That's a lot easier to understand.

Comment: What does the `$mediaarray` and `$mediafiletype` looks like ? can you give example values ?

Comment: Thanks for replys. The notsure varible was just a error when copying the code over. I will take your advise on board and i will double check the tables and get back with a more clearer edited question.